# Building (Binary Tree) DOM Tree from html

Tags: java, binary-tree

My project requires me to take html code formatted like this:

```
<html>
<body>
The 
<b>
quick
</b>
 brown fox
</body>
</html>
```

From here, I would have to make a DOM tree like this:

```
   ----------
    |html| |\|
    ------|---
          |
          V
       ----------
       |body| |\|
       ------|---
             |
             V
          ----------   -------   ----------------
          |The |\|-|-> |b| |-|-> | brown fox|\|\|
          ----------   ---|---   ----------------
                          |
                          V
                       -----------
                       |quick|\|\|
                       -----------
```

I am either thinking to use a stack or recursion, but I'm not sure which method will be best. To me, this looks like a binary tree, where the left tree would be children, and the right tree would be a sibling. It looks like if the previous node was text, the current node becomes a sibling. The code broken down could look like this:

```
<html> -root
 <body> -child
  The -child
  <b> -sibling
   quick -child
  </b> -return
  brown fox -sibling
 </body
<html
```

Edit:
To build the tree just keep reading the next line with the scanner. If it doesn't have a "/" in it push it onto the stack. When you read in a line with a "/" ..()...then you're going to keep popping from the stack until you find the matching tag without the "/" so . Everything that's popped will be connected as siblings and when you get to the final pop which is the matching tag you'll make its firstChild the last popped tag.

```
public void build() {
    Stack<TagNode> tags = new Stack<TagNode>();
    Stack<TagNode> reverse = new Stack<TagNode>();

    while(sc.hasNext()){
        String curr = sc.nextLine();

        if(!curr.contains("/")){ //is an open tag or text, push it
            tags.push(new TagNode(curr,null,null));
        }else{ //is a closing tag
            TagNode base = tags.pop();
            while(tags.peek().tag.equals(curr.replaceFirst("/", ""))){ //while we haven't hit the opening tag yet, take the first node, then add everything else as siblings
                TagNode temp = tags.pop();
                temp.sibling = base;
                base = temp;
            }
            tags.peek().firstChild = base;
            root = tags.peek();
        }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what that question is. But conceptually, it's a non-binary tree. `body` has three children: [`The`, `<b>quick</b>`, `brown fox`]. Whether you represent this by giving parent a list of children, or a link to just its first child, which is the head of a linked list (which seems to be what you did), it's not really a binary tree. Is that maybe where the confusion is stemming from?

Comment: I need to create a method that will build a DOM tree from the given html. I see what you mean about body having 3 total children, but no node has more than 2 pointers, or more than 1 pointing to it. To me this sounds recursive, where the base case would be where there is no more text to parse, and depending on the current state of a current pointer and a previous pointer, we could determine where to place the new node (child or sibling)

Comment: Recursion sounds like a good approach to me. But why does each node have to have no more than 2 pointers (I assume you mean to children nodes)? For instance, couldn't `body` point to all three of its children? You could do this by having each `Node` contain a `List<Node> children` which can have 0 or more elements. The `Node` for `body` would have `children.size() == 3`, for instance.

Comment: I tried to go with using a stack instead and I think I have a good idea now. For my program I have to use a TagNode, which is defined as having a firstChild and sibling, as its only pointers. I updated above...

Comment: What type of tree is the DOM? It's obviously not a binary tree as each child can have multiple children. I haven't found a clear answer to this on SO.